# sound when clicking a button works for one but not for ALL

Tags: javascript

Can someone show me why if I try to play a sound like so

```
const button = document.querySelector(".button");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.getElementById("click").play("click.mp3");
});
```

the sound will only play on the first button (I understand this since it is targeting the first element) with the class .button but if I use querySlectorAll it does not play at all please?

And how can I make it play in all the buttons with the class .button?

Thanks in advance.

Thanks to Barmar for suggesting to use a loop.
I did like in below and it works great.

```
for (let button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("click").play("click.mp3");
  });
  console.log(button);
}
```

Comment: When you use `querySelectorAll()` you need to write a loop to add the event listener to all of them.

Comment: *"but if I use querySlectorAll"* - (1) You don't use that in the code shown.  (2) There's a typo, which is certainly producing an error.  Do you have an example of something you've tried which isn't working in a specific way?  Currently you're showing us code that works, indicating how and why you understand that it works, and asking us why some other code you aren't showing us doesn't work.

Comment: `but if I use querySlectorAll it does not play at all please?` Please [edit] your question to show your attempt on querySelectoAll.

Comment: If you want all buttons with a .class button, I wouldn't use `querySelectAll` anyway, a much better approach is a delegated event..

Answer (score 0):

In my case efficient solution will be addEventListener to the parent that contain these buttons and make a check condition that if clicked element has some class or data attribute then make your sound play.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way would be to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), which returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which can be [coerced into an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```js
const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".button"));

buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.getElementById("click").play("click.mp3");
    });
});
```